# Make two <div>s overlap?

Tags: css, html

I'm having a problem getting my container to close so after I make this markup my header I would like to add other items underneath but not part of the container - If this makes sense.
I have no idea why not but this CSS is not closing and it is basically just making everything under it part of the same CSS

CSS :

```
.menuButton {
    background-color: #8dd1c5;
    width: 252px;
    height: 52px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 198px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

user agent stylesheeta:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}

.menuContainer .menuWrap {
    width: 222px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 2px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#pusher {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.pagesContainer .pageContainer {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 770px;
    min-height: 570px;
}

.pagesContainer .pageContainer .pageBackgroundContainer {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.hiddenPageButton, .hiddenMenuButton {
    top: 228px;
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.pagesContainer .pageContainer .topBorderText,
.pagesContainer .pageContainer .bottomBorderText {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.pagesContainer .pageContainer .bottomBorderText {
    bottom: 0;
    top: auto;
}

.pagesContainer .pageContainer {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 770px;
    min-height: 570px;
}

html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1600px;
    min-height: 570px;
}

.menuContainer {
    min-height: 510px;
    width: 222px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 3000;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

The html:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=g0STLR3u

The problem is that the container takes up the whole page I just want it to take up the top header part.

Please help!

Comment: Your link acts crazy...

Comment: Replicating a simplified version of the problem in a jsfiddle will make the problem easier to diagnose.

Comment: please clarify only your problem, not share here your all source code. if any body cant understand your question, then you want your questions answer properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to create menu like this **[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/XWmVG/)**

I have used `<ul>` and `<li>` for them, check it out:

HTML:

```
<div class="menuButton">
    <ul>
        <li>Navigation</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Credit</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuButton ul li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.menuButton {
    background-color: #8dd1c5;
    width: 500px;
    height: 52px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 198px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Change `min-height: 570px` to `min-height: 100%` as following :

```
.pagesContainer .pageContainer {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 770px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You can see how it looks live here: flexablerunner.tumblr.com As you can see when you scroll down that bar is still fixed. When I set it to absolute all my links are non click able. The HTML:                            <div class="pageContainer" data-pageid="mainMenu-24" id="_cafe_delikatess_" style="position: relative; top: 0px; height:100px; bottom: 0px; display: none; z-index: 0; left: 0px;">
 <div class="pageBackgroundContainer">
 <div class="pageBorder">
 <div class="borderLeft"></div>
 <div class="borderTop"></div>
 <div class="borderRight"></div>
 <div class="borderBottom"></div></div>

Comment: Thanks for replying. I changed it and it fixed the border but the links are not clickable. You can check my site again to see. The posts can't be clicked either. I was thinking maybe it's the container or it's in the same div? Right when I paste the code you gave me it changed the bottom border to be good but also made the links un clickable. I hope you understand what I'm saying, and other help would be appreciated I've tried everything. I was thinking maybe the html positioning of the page container was it? http://gyazo.com/823439fabd9c4e7fbe72f9b091c976ca.png I think it's the positioning?

Comment: Are the link clickable before the change in `min-height`?

Comment: Which post is unclickable? The images and post are perfectly clickable.

Comment: Yes they were clickable before I changed it. And you looked once I got it working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please add right:0 and top:0

tag

```
<h2>
 <b style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px;">
   EXPRESSION ON TUMBLR
  </b>
</h2>
```

Comment: I did but it only changes the position of the text not the container

Comment: i think you have a z-index: issue;